# Racktables and DHCP

Tags: networking, documentation, ipam

For those of you out there using Racktables, how do you handle DHCP scopes? I haven't been able to find a way to show the IP addresses as allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RackTables is not really an IPAM but a rack manager. You should take a look at **PHP-IP**, **GestióIP** and **phpIPAM**.

Comment: IPAM == IP Address Manager (just in case somebody wondered...) In RackSpace you can define the scopes and also keep track of the static assignments which you enter manually or from a SNMP probe if your devices are capable. But it has no provisions to read the dynamic leases from a DHCP server as far as I know.